# expand variables, but do not run any functions

Tags: php

Fairly hard to formulate it right, so I'll show an example I want to achieve:

```
$x = 'one';
$y = 123123;

$z = foo(bar($x, $y));
// $z = 'bar(one, 123123)'
```

Basically, I want this magic foo function to expand every variable to it's value, but the function to stay as a string. What's the best way to do this? Is it possible to do this without extracting the variables with str_replace and similar? How can we interpret the function as a string?
The requirements are that the function should be called like above, and not like a string:
`foo('bar($x, $y)');`

Comment: For example to get/set memcache:
$mc->output(mysql_query($sql));
will get value from memcache, if there is one, and set if there are no and output query

Comment: @Vlakarados - just to clarify your needs - are you intending to use the function name and variables as the key to the memcached value? i.e. `'bar(one, 123123)'` is the key you use to store and retrieve the result of `bar(one, 123123)`

Comment: yes, for example like that, I know it may not be the best way, but it will give me unique keys and it's automatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do it this way.

When foo() enters into play, it receives the results of bar() already processed. Therefore, it has no access to the environment that generated them (i.e. the name of the function bar() or its paramerers). If you wished to use this foo() on generic functions, then I believe that it is not possible.

You could do something like passing the arguments ('bar', $x and $y) to foo, which would become a variable-arguments function, and have this new foo() call your 'bar' (the first argument passed as string, which would be the name of the function). But you may have performance penalties, plus you could have problems with variables scoping...

Comment: that's like I think it is.. but may there be a way to send a pointer to a function? something like foo(&bar(..)); ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, so maybe I'm way off here, but it looks to me that you are trying to use a callback. You can implement that in different ways, but one way is to use an anonymous function (Supported from php 5.4).

```
$x = 'one';
$y = 123123;
$z = foo(function() use ($x,$y) { bar($x, $y); });
```

Your function `foo` would then invoke it like thusly:

```
function foo($callback) {
  call_user_func($callback);
}
```

Is that it?

Comment: not entirely sure what anonymous function actually is, got to do some reading on this one, but as to callbacks - no, I need to get back the function as a string BUT with argument variables as values, not their names

Comment: What is the use case for that?

Comment: in the comments for the answer above

Answer (score -3):

Well, if you want such a functionality, you have to implement FULL MVC pattern, including Model.

Thus, you will have no ugly raw mysql calls in the Controller (or even View).

And your code will become like

```
$mc->output($obj->getdata());
```

where `$obj` is a model object and `getdata()` is a method that returns required data, performing all the fetching logic inside, getting the data either from the cache or database.

Comment: Yes, I have full MVC, so how can I make it work then? getdata() from your example should have parameters too

Comment: you can use this function with parameters

Comment: Well, looks like you didn't get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve, you simply wrote it in OOP way, but what do I need is a way to get '$obj->getdata()' as a string in return

Comment: That's kind of answer explaining that your architectural approach is wrong and you'd better follow more common patterns to save you some troubles like this one.